# Timeout in shell script (Mac OS)

Tags: macos, shell

I'm running shell script and waiting for receiving a notification

```
Here doing something
notifyutil -1 notification_name &
wait    
Here doing something again
```

I would like to implement timeout, i.e. I would like to wait only 10 seconds for this notification. The problem is that I need to know if I have received notification, or timeout has occurred. Do you have any ideas?